# CustomPainter only takes up visible screen

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, render, flutter-custompainter

I have a map in the form of an Image which is scrollable horizontally, and custom Painter which seems to only take the space of the screen currently being displayed and scrolls across the image instead of staying in it's place.

[image: This is what is displayed as soon as I open the page]

[image: However, it scrolls on top of the image, while it drags the custom painter with it]

As it can be seen the image stayed in its place and was scrolled over, while the `customPainter`(reddish ball) was dragged. I tried using a `singleScrollChildView` but it doesn't work because I have the size of the `CustomPainter` as `infinite` which doesn't allow it. The reason I want it to be scrollable is that I want to use the it as a way of drawing on the map.

A sample code of the last attempt can be seen below:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
          false, //helps change the gadegst to fit in case other widgets appear
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _mainService.getOrCreateUser(theemail: userEmail),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      //scroll widget
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            //loads an image on to the app
                            'images/map.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.14,
                        child: buildFloatingSearchBar(context),
                      ),
                    ),
                    IgnorePointer(
                      ignoring: true,

                     

                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
                        child: CustomPaint(
                          willChange: true,
                          size: Size.infinite,

                          //MediaQuery.of(context).size,
                          painter: LocationCircles(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );

            default:
              return spinkit2;
          }
        },
      ),
```